# HttpPost view post params

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'd like to be able to view the complete `HttpClient` / `HttpPost URI` with params. I'm not sure how to output it to my console.

```
HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
httppost.setHeader("ContentType","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));
System.out.println(httppost.getURI());
```

Printing `getURI` only outputs the `baseURI` and not the params.

Could someone help me with what I'm missing?

Comment: the post is defined as javing the parameters in the body of the requsst. you need to dump the body

Comment: @thst could you provide and answer demonstrating how to achieve this?

Comment: You could do something like: `System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(httppost.getEntity(), "utf-8"));`.

Answer (score 1):

The entity has a method to serialize itself to an output stream `writeTo()`, so you can create one and dump the entity there. This is not the whole request, only the `UrlEncodedFormEntity` exposing the encoded parameters:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream outs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
httppost.getEntity().writeTo(outs);
System.out.println(outs.toString("UTF-8"));
outs.close();
```

result is one line like this:

```
foul=play&foo=bar&baz=bam
```